# JQuery css() on.('click' ... doesn't work

Tags: jquery

Here is my JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul.navbar").on("click", "li", function() {
        $(this).find("h2").css("color: pink");
        alert($(this).text());
        alert($(this).find("h2").text());
    });
});
```

The click generates the alerts correctly, but the color of the text does not change. I've tried `.addClass()` too and that also does not work. Any ideas? I've perused a lot of the other similar questions but not found them helpful, I'm a real newb to Javascript and still stuck.

Comment: I'm so glad jQuery provides documentation which shows the proper usage of each method, for example: http://api.jquery.com/css. I'm able to solve my problems quickly by just reading the documentation. You should give it a try too!

Comment: There is no need to be rude! I have a more general problem than the use of the css function, as correcting the syntax makes no difference. As mentioned replacing css() with addClass() does not work either.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't meant to be rude, just a bit sardonic. If you already had the function call fixed, then you could have focused the question on your actual problem. But if the fixing the `.css` call does not lead to the expected behavior, then you have to provide more information. As you can see here, the JavaScript itself works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/qxk98/.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `.css()` incorrectly -

It should be like this -

```
$(this).find("h2").css("color","pink");
```

API `--->` http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
$(this).find("h2").css("color: pink");
```

to that:

```
$(this).find("h2").css("color", "pink");
```

Comment: Correcting my mistake here does not make any difference. No matter what I put inside the function, it does not work, except the alert. Probably I have selected the wrong element, but I have been fiddling with this for ages and can't seem to hit on the right thing.

Comment: Attach also your HTML so then we can verify what is wrong there, or the best make jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 2):

JQuery css function takes two parameters, you are using it incorrectly.

Correct parameters are as below

```
$(this).find("h2").css("color" ,"pink");
```

Answer (score 1):

or this:

```
$(this).find("h2").css( {color: "pink" } );
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's CSS function takes arguments in two styles:

- As a single name/value pair:

  ```
  .css('stylename' , 'value')
  ```

  Two parameters in the function call, so separated by a comma.

  ...in which case, your code would look like this:

  ```
  .css('color', 'pink')`
  ```

  Note: Both parameters are strings, so must be in quotes. It doesn't matter whether you use single or double quotes.
- As an object containing multiple name/value pairs:

  ```
  .css({'stylename':'value' , 'stylename':'value' , etc})
  ```

  One parameter, but defined as an object, so enclosed in curly braces; each name/value separated from each other by a colon; and each pair of name/values separated by a comma.

  ...in which case, your code would look like this:

  ```
  .css({'color': 'pink'})`
  ```

  As before, it doesn't matter about single or double quotes, but note that since this is an object structure, the quotes around the style names are optional (although not in all cases, so it's probably best to stick to always having them).

The first syntax was originally the only one available; the latter syntax was added in a later version of jQuery to allow more than one style to be set in a single call.

If you're only changing a single style value then it doesn't matter which syntax you use. If you're changing more than one style at a time, then obviously it's better to use the second syntax rather than making multiple calls using the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work for me:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul.navbar").on("click", "li", function() {
        $(this).find("h2").css("color","pink");
        alert($(this).text());
        alert($(this).find("h2").text());
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dT7gW/)

Which jQuery are you using?